# Woocommerce Help - selling fonts - multiple options downloadable products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

Basically this is my issue.

I am trying to develop a Font Foundry website where people can buy and download fonts.

I need to achieve this:

For every single weight of a font (ex: helvetica light) I need users to be able to select between a:

- desktop version (default option - which has a price - ex: 29$)
- web version (which has an individual price of - ex: 14$ which is +14$ when selected with the desktop version)
- both of them (discounted price of them together)

If the user buys only the desktop version, he should be able to download just that one. If the user buys both, he should, of course, be able to download both.

I have been looking into multiple extension but I can't find a way to achieve this. I need help so that I can buy all that I need.

Thank you.

Comment: did you check out [DynamicPricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) or [ProductBundles](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/)?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a Variable product? Variation 1 = desktop. Variation 2 = Web. Variation 3 = both?

Comment: @meatspace unfortunately they won't help. 
DynamicPricing allows me to give discount to who i choose to regarding quantity - to single products and not assembled packages ( I can achieve this with the bundles)

The real problem is the other thing - being able in a single product to choose between different options with different prices and different download files and none of these extension allow me to do that :(

Comment: @helgatheviking - with the variable products the problem is this:
when i add a variable (ex. Web Version) - the user is then Obliged to choose a Web version variable - it means that i can't ignore the variable and not choose a Web version.

Comment: Why not? If the user chose the desktop version you could ignore the web version?

Comment: @helgatheviking I was able to make it work like this:
No - you can't ignore it - when you add a variable then the user must set a value there.

So basically I've created an "empty" value - "none" with no price change and no download attached.